# Angular - Rendering image/jpeg data from API

Tags: angular

My http call:

`return http.get(url).map(res => res.text());`

Component:

```
 httpService.getCustomBanner('path').subscribe(
 data => {
     this.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ data
 })
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf = "image">
    <img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image)"/>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any errors, and the API is returning a type of image/jpeg, 
but nothing is rendering.

Edit: Taking out the `data:image/jpeg;base64` along with dee zg's answer is what fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your http call you need something like this (not tested, writing from head):

```
.map(res => res.blob())
.map(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
```

that will return you a `DomString` which you can feed into your img source.

Comment: My `image` variable now seems to be populated, but I'm getting that generic image icon.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I tried so many posts but this one works for me. For others, I will post my experience here. For my testing, my asp.net core API returns a student list with byte[] data type image which is mapped to Blob in Angular.
In addition, in Angular field names in a class must start with a lower case for reference regardless of their declaration. eg.

```
 Student.Photo; // is declared in a Student class. 

 students: Student[];
 //Call an api and put the result into students. 
 students[0].photo worked. But students[0].Photo caused an error of 'undefined'.
```

For working sample of multiple images, please see the below codes.

--Angular component HTML -----

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of studentList">
        <td>{{item?.given1}}   --  {{item?.surname}}</td>

        <td>          
            <img [src]="getImangeUrl(item?.photo)"/>
        </td>        
</tr>
```

-- in component.ts file

```
public getImangeUrl(photo:Blob): any {    
    if (photo === null)
      return "";
    else
    {
      let objectURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + photo;
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);   
    }
  }
```

Finally it works for me. Most examples are only for a single image which is very easy to do it as the above example. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

in your component define a function

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

sanity(url)
{
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url)
}
```

and in the template you can use

```
<div *ngIf = "image">
<img [src]="sanity(image)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: url of the image

Comment: Gotcha. Nothing changes though.

Answer (score 0):

hi I am not sure about [src] but you can use the following code and test if it works for you

```
<div *ngIf = "image">
    <img src="{{sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image)}}"/>
</div>
```